# Formatting HTML style in PyCharm

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, pycharm

How to automatically generate tabs to get a proper tree view on a generated HTML file?

For example, I've got a code like this:

```
    def creating_html(self):
    something ='''<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
'''
    file.write(something)
```

This code will generate code with proper tabs etc. but I feel my code is really messy because of that and also I think that I'm wasting time to check for a good format. So I was thinking about something like this, to make my code little bit cleaner.

```
    def creating_html(self):
    something ='''
            <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            '''
    file.write(something)
```

but now the format is of course invalid.

I was searching for a good solution and one of them is just open this HTML file after generating it with PyCharm and use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. I'm looking for a solution to do it automatically.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for editing and sorry for my messy english. I'm still learning. :)

Comment: How does that make your code cleaner? It makes the inline HTML harder to read. And who is going to be reading it once generated anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Beautiful Soup 4 installing it with pip and use it like follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
something ='''
        <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        '''
messed_code= BeautifulSoup(something, 'html.parser')
file.write(messed_code.prettify())
```

Personally, I think the string looks better in the first case as far as it's more readable

Comment: actually I need to work not on a something, because I've got a lot of "something's" which is sticked after. That's why I need to work on this writed file, but I'll read more about this beautifulSoup I'm 99% sure it will work for me, thanks :)

Comment: I guess you could read the file and pass its string in order to beautify it with beautiful soup

Comment: Yeah, I think its a good solution, I'll try after dinner, really thanks :-)

Comment: Glad to help you! If you feel this is a suitable answer, please accept it as an answer to close the post :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from lxml import etree, html
html_string ='''
            <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            '''
html_object = html.fromstring(html_string)
file.write(etree.tostring(html_object, pretty_print=True))
```